# Auto Fill some fields in Odoo 11

Tags: odoo-10, autofill

I work on transportation module related to sale.order module 
I added transportation tab on `sale.order` module where it pool its data from the built-in module (available in odoo 11)called fleet.vehicle
I want that when I select vehicle name,
other fields in the tab are filled automatically such as chassis number, license plate,....
my code is below(it does not work)

```py
@api.onchange("model_id")   
def onchange_lines(self):
  if self.model_id:         
      cr = self.pool.cursor()
      check=self.pool['fleet.vehicle'].search(cr, self.env.uid,['model_id','=',self.model_id])
      for record in check:
         if record:
            self.vin_sn=record[vin_sn]
```

I work on ubuntu and odoo11
please help
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your onchange on selection field of vehicle name. Not on model_id. After that in onchange first check if you are getting vehicle then you can get related field value in self or else create browseable object and return value whatever you want.

Comment: but I have each unique model_id have unique chassis number and license plate, I donot have duplicated model_id, I juust want to know  why this code is not working